# Making push notifications with websockets

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, push-notification, starscream

I've set up an app to send motion data from one device to another using websockets (Starscream library). Now I need to send push notifications when a critical event happens (when app is minimized), does it have anything to do with websockets or I just need to use something like Pusher?

Comment: On iOS, once your app is no longer active, connections will be suspended after a short while, and so will your sockets. You'll have to resort to actual push notifications to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, I think you should use Pusher or any other external service (Pushwoosh, Onesignal, among others) to send push notifications to the users. You can't do this with websockets.

I recommend you to use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) (it is free and some big companies like Uber or Zillow are using it)

**EDIT**:

I think you can't send a push notification from one device to the other one. One device (let's say Kid.app) should notify the server of an event, and then the server will send the push notification to the other (Parent.app).

Check [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial), it will be useful for you.

Comment: What if my task is to send notification from one app to a different one (like Kid.app and Parent.app)?